# Python combined condition operators: if AA in Y or BB in Y and not B in Y

Tags: python

I want to run this code as "if `'Britain'` or `'UK'` in string do stuff, but don't do stuff if `"Ex UK"` is in string":

```
#Case insensitive wrapper - equivalent to if X in Y
def case_in(phrase, string):
    return phrase.lower() in string.lower()

name = "Developed Europe Ex UK Property"

#This is the relevant part
if case_in("Britain", name) or case_in(" UK ", name) and not case_in("Ex UK", name):
    geofocusregion = "Europe"
    geofocuscountry = "GB"
    fundcurrency = "GBP"
```

However, for a string where `"Ex UK"` is included, it still sets the variables, e.g. `geofocuscountry = GB`.

Comment: The `if` condition will be false for the example you gave, and it will not perform the assignments. You need to show a real example that demonstrates the problem, and show how you know that it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python [the precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) of `and` is higher than `or` so you need to put the first 2 conditions within a parenthesis.

```
if (case_in("Britain", name) or case_in(" UK ", name)) and not case_in("Ex UK", name):
```

Answer (score 1):

if (case_in("Britain", name) or case_in(" UK ", name)) and not case_in("Ex UK", name):

group the first two conditions together.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this if you are not aware of precedence orders

```
if "Britain" in name or " UK " in name:
    if not "Ex UK" in name:
        geofocusregion = "Europe"
        geofocuscountry = "GB"
        fundcurrency = "GBP"
```